# THREE.js not drawing nested objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to javascript and yes, this is my homework (I'm soooo sorry).

TL;DR VERSION: object has array of objects and the have array of objects, first array is drawn in canvas, second isn't. (I'm C# programmer, it is not in missing one loop)

FULL VERSION: Solar system. Object Solar system holds only Array of planets

```
function SolarSystem() { this.Planets = new Array(); }
```

Object Planet has some properties and holds array of "moons," which are also Planet objects:

```
function Planet(name, timeOfOrbit, radiusOfOrbit, radiusOfPlanet, spinningSpeed, texture) {
    this.name = name;
    this.spinningSpeed = spinningSpeed;
    this.timeOfOrbit = timeOfOrbit;
    this.radiusOfPlanet = km2au(radiusOfPlanet);
    this.radiusOfOrbit = radiusOfOrbit;
    this.texture = texture;
    this.moons = new Array();

    //Private variable created in constructor, accessible through getter
    var angularVelocity = (2 * Math.PI) / timeOfOrbit;
    var THREEObject = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radiusOfPlanet * 200, 32, 32), texture);
    this.getTHREEObject = function () {
        return THREEObject;
    }

    this.getTHREEObject().position.x = this.radiusOfOrbit;

    //TO DO: calculate positions of moons from planet.moons
    this.move = function () {
        var theta = angularVelocity * dayOfAnimation;
        var x = this.radiusOfOrbit * Math.cos(theta);
        var y = this.radiusOfOrbit * Math.sin(theta);
        this.getTHREEObject().position.x = x
        this.getTHREEObject().position.y = y;
        if (spinningSpeed != -1) this.getTHREEObject().rotation.z = dayOfAnimation * (Math.PI * 2) / spinningSpeed;

        this.moons.forEach(function (moon, index, array) {
            var moonTheta = moon.angularVelocity * dayOfAnimation;                
            array[index].getTHREEObject().position.x = x + moon.radiusOfOrbit * Math.cos(moonTheta);
            array[index].getTHREEObject().position.y = y + moon.radiusOfOrbit * Math.sin(moonTheta);
        });
    }
}
```

This is how I add planet:

```
    var Mars = new Planet("Mars", 687, 1.381 * 2, 3541 * 10, 24, materials.Mars());
    var Phobos = new Planet("Phobos", 0.319, km2au(9376), 27 * 10, -1, materials.Moon());
    var Deimos = new Planet("Deimos", 1.263, km2au(23463), 15 * 10, -1, materials.Moon());
    Mars.moons.push(Phobos);
    Mars.moons.push(Deimos);
    solarSystem.Planets.push(Mars);
```

This is how I add drawable objects to scene:

```
solarSystem.Planets.forEach(function (planet) {
        obj.add(planet.getTHREEObject());
        planet.moons.forEach(function (moon) {
            obj.add(moon.getTHREEObject());
        });
    });
```

This is how I run timer:

```
   window.setInterval(function () {
        solarSystem.Planets.forEach(function (planet) 
        {
            planet.move();
        });
        dayOfAnimation++;
    }, intervalConstant);
```

I guess that the problem is that I'm used to work with reference-passed parameters, while JS is somehow... wierd... for me. Why can't I reference object from which I call foreach (planet.Move => foreach (moon) can't call back to planet?)? Could you (/*FU****G GOD D**N IT*/) PLEASE point me to solution / show me the correct approach on how to solve this?

P.s.: I have read some texts about passing parameters in JS, but to be honest... I'm not really sure I understand... A damn thing :D

P.s.s.: I tried even creating object Moon, which holds (not) reference to parent planet. Well, also not working.

Comment: Mars's radius is `3541 * 10` km while the radius of the orbit of Deimos is `23463` km. Is it correct?

Comment: No, those * 10 are there so the planets are visible. In original scale (Mars's radius is 3541) it is almost impossible to spot those planets.

Comment: What I want to say is that according to your code, it seems that Phobos and Deimos are rotating _inside_ of Mars (because 23463, the radius of the orbit of Deimos, is less than the radius of Mars, 35410), so they are invisible anyway.

Comment: I though of that and tried even to look inside of those spheres (and of course, I tried to run it with propper sizes, originals or magnified accordingly), yet nothing happens.